# Disable CSS3 fade in when submit button is clicked

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a fade in effect working perfect when my login page loads.

I am using a form to collect username and password from the user which is connected to a database.  I also have a PHP error that shows when the username and password is incorrect or no data has been inserted.

My issue is that when i click submit without entering anything my page will fade in again then shows the error.

How can i stop the page fading in when the error messages show?

I only really want the page to fade in when the user first enters the website.

CSS:

```
  body{
 animation: fadein 1.5s;}

   @keyframes fadein {
   from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

PHP showing error:

```
  <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
```

Comment: Are you reloading the page after submitting the form?

Comment: If the details are incorrect then it reloads the page and displays the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution will be to require client-side validation for your form. This will prevent the page from re-loading every time the submit button is pushed and the form is not complete or satisfactory.

Add the 'required' attribute to your inputs (at the minimum) or add some JS validation.

For example:

```
  <input type="text" id="username" required>
  <input type="password" id="password" required">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

This is supported in most browsers. https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

It's a best practice to supplement this with javascript validation, too. You can find additional information on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

EDIT: To answer your comment:

As you're seeing, the only thing that client-side validation will check for is (a) completion, and/or (b) a pattern condition (like a regex or HTML5 condition [input type="email", input type="number", etc.]).

Validating a username and password against existing users in a database will fall to PHP validation (or another server-side handler). Without using AJAX, there's not a way to check for correct username/password without reloading the page. Assuming you'd like to skip learning AJAX for this, you might try the following:

```
If (username) and (password) == (username) and (password)
{redirect to ('success.html')}
else {redirect to ('fail.html')}
NOTE: THIS IS AN OUTLINE OF CONCEPT -- NOT THE ACTUAL CODE
```

On 'fail.html' do not include the fade-in. This would mean that the user will go to the login page (which will fade-in) and from there go to either the success page or the fail page, neither of which will include code to fade-in.

Comment: This does stop thepage from loading when nothing is entered but when a wrong username or password is entered then the page still loads.

Comment: Thanks @hypern00b  I am thinking AJAX would be the best way to achieve what i want.  I know very little about AJAX but i think learning it for this purpose will be worth it and hoping it doesnt take too long to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

You could echo a style in addition to the error, which would overwrite the animation. For example:

```
<style>
   body{
      animation:unset !important;
   }
</style>
```

Use the *!important* only if your error is echoed before the css.

Comment: sorry i thought this worked but it actually stopped the animation working at all.